# Domains seemingly throttling my connection since I switched ISPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, isp, throttling

### Overview

I recently switched internet service providers and ever since I've been having issues loading certain sites. The tech support folks were of little help, and I suspect the root cause is something more technical, as power-cycling my router and using an ethernet connection did not help.

### The Problem

Occasionally, certain sites seem to dramatically throttle my connection speed. Additionally, only that but my work VPN (through AWS) banned my IP due to its WAF rules.
Finally, when a site loaded slowly, it seemed that most other sites in that domain experienced the same issue, but only on my home internet. Using a hotspot resolved the issue, so it was not the server itself having issues.
This all indicated to me that at least AWS and maybe other cloud service providers are viewing my traffic as somehow malicious

Just to show that it's download speed and not something else, here's the normal page load followed by the slow page load. Queue times seem reasonable but the download times just seem significantly longer

[image: Normal]

[image: Throttled]

### One last note

During one of these slow-downs, I tried directly downloading some of the slow files (namely that batch.js?agile_global file) via postman, and the slowdowns weren't present. I did replicate it later, though, but it wasn't happening on my browser at that time (maybe different user-agent?)

Comment: Have you considered using a different DNS provider? A web server cannot typically throttle a client that is connected. I only say typically since I cannot think of any process where that would be possible but I won't rule out the possibility